Memory-Efficient PyTorch DataLoader for Training Neural Networks with Large Input
I have a dataset consisting of many large matrices (circa 200x200). From these matrices, I extract numerous smaller submatrices (e.g., 20x20). Now, I need to use these submatrices to train a PyTorch neural network. However, the original matrices are too large to be stored in memory all at once. Is there a method to create a 'symbolic' DataLoader in PyTorch, where I can embed the operations needed to extract the submatrices directly during training? I'm looking for a memory-efficient solution that avoids storing the entire dataset in memory simultaneously. Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Consider serialize them to the disk and load them when called?

Thank you for your reply, is it any way to do this efficiently?

Just use pickles.dump() or torch.save() your large tensors and load them when you call __getitem__()

Thank you again, what if the data is numpy and converting to torch clogs the memory?

If they are already in numpy format, you can use np.save and np.load directly. Though if you are using them for training, you still need to convert them to torch Tensor anyway.
